# JavaScript Anonymous Functions Array to Java Translation

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, function-pointers, anonymous-function

I asked a similar question before I haven't gotten any good feedback/help there. So I am rewriting this question with more information.

Here is a partially converted Javascript Function to Java.. It's nearly complete.
I know I cannot use Anonymous Functions in arrays in Java let alone Anonymous Functions, only thing closest to this functionality would be inner-classes, not what I want.

I know this code can still be converted maybe into multiple functions and instead of using Anonymous Function Arrays something like if statements or a mix of a `switch(...)`

The function below just initalizes the LINECONTROL array of anonymous functions using recursion calls as well.

Later in this javscript emulator It's used like this

```
LCDCONTROL = (LCDisOn) ? LINECONTROL : DISPLAYOFFCONTROL;
```

`DISPLAYOFFCONTROL` is a anonymous function that's empty.
declared like this

```
 DISPLAYOFFCONTROL = [function() {}];
```

You never call the `LINECONTROL` array outside the `initalizeLCDController`, you only call the `LCDCONTROL` object.

Like so

```
//LCDCONTROL[actualScanLine]();
```

I just need some advise how to to convert to function below maybe just a head start that's about it.

Here is the partially translated function from JavaScript -> Java

```
public void initializeLCDController() {
    long a = 0;
    while (a < 154) {
        if (a < 143) {
            LINECONTROL[a] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks < 80) {
                    scanLineMode2();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 252) {
                    scanLineMode3();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 456) {
                    scanLineMode0();
                } else {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    if (STATTracker != 3) {
                        if (STATTracker != 2) {
                            if (STATTracker == 0 && mode2TriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            }
                            incrementScanLineQueue();
                        }
                        if (hdmaRunning) {
                            executeHDMA();
                        }
                        if (mode0TriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    actualScanLine = ++memory[65348];
                    if (actualScanLine == memory[65349]) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    checkIRQMatching();
                    STATTracker = 0;
                    modeSTAT = 2;
                    LINECONTROL[actualScanLine]();
                }
            }
        } else if (a == 143) {
            LINECONTROL[143] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks < 80) {
                    scanLineMode2();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 252) {
                    scanLineMode3();
                } else if (LCDTicks < 456) {
                    scanLineMode0();
                } else {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    if (STATTracker != 3) {
                        if (STATTracker != 2) {
                            if (STATTracker == 0 && mode2TriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            }
                            incrementScanLineQueue();
                        }
                        if (hdmaRunning) {
                            executeHDMA();
                        }
                        if (mode0TriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    actualScanLine = memory[65348] = 144;
                    if (memory[65349] == 144) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    STATTracker = 0;
                    modeSTAT = 1;
                    interruptsRequested |= (mode1TriggerSTAT) ? 3 : 1;
                    checkIRQMatching();
                    if (drewBlank == 0) {
                        if (totalLinesPassed < 144 || (totalLinesPassed == 144 && midScanlineOffset > -1)) {
                            graphicsJITVBlank();
                            prepareFrame();
                        }
                    } else {
                        --drewBlank;
                    }
                    LINECONTROL[144]();
                }
            }
        } else if (a < 153) {
            LINECONTROL[a] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks >= 456) {
                    LCDTicks -= 456;
                    actualScanLine = ++memory[65348];
                    if (actualScanLine == memory[65349]) {
                        memory[65345] |= 4;
                        if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                            interruptsRequested |= 2;
                            checkIRQMatching();
                        }
                    } else {
                        memory[65345] &= 123;
                    }
                    LINECONTROL[actualScanLine]();
                }
            }
        } else {
            LINECONTROL[153] = function () {
                if (LCDTicks >= 8) {
                    if (STATTracker != 4 && memory[65348] == 153) {
                        memory[65348] = 0;
                        if (memory[65349] == 0) {
                            memory[65345] |= 4;
                            if (LYCMatchTriggerSTAT) {
                                interruptsRequested |= 2;
                                checkIRQMatching();
                            }
                        } else {
                            memory[65345] &= 123;
                        }
                        STATTracker = 4;
                    }
                    if (LCDTicks >= 456) {
                        LCDTicks -= 456;
                        STATTracker = actualScanLine = 0;
                        LINECONTROL[0]();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ++a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring Java 8 lambdas, what was wrong with anonymous inner classes that implement ```Runnable``` or ```Callable```? (though with a tidied-up init sequence; no need to make identical objects that do the same thing, but your JS might already be doing this)

Comment: I haven't tried those, I want it to be fast as well since it's a VM reason I started to port it from Javascript to Java because when running it on Rhino Javascript Engine for Java it used too much CPU/Memory now when I comment out this code it runs at 2% cpu pretty good only it doesn't work. This LCDCONTROL  is called where the instructions are executed in the VM so I don't want to slow it down I want to keep it simple. Yeah I use Java 7. Yes I want to avoid making a bunch of functions.. that do nearly the same functions. Thats why I think I could solve this with a switch() or if statements

Comment: There are different patterns for what you're trying to do. One, the most direct, is with anonymous inner classes (which you don't want, but I'm not sure why). Another is with enums while also maintaining the jump table (should be fast), and the answer that's so simple--just make each one a method--I'm thinking there's a reason you don't want.

Comment: This code shouldn't be that slow, even in Rhino. Are you sure one of those other functions isn't polling?

Comment: Eh with Rhino it created a bunch of anonymous classes I guess it had memory leaks the memory kept growing rapidly when I ran the execute instruction function in another function that ended calling it self every 10 milliseconds using a setTimeout() that's how it was in javascript to begin with. In Browser it's always 17-25% cpu in Rhino it's always 100%.. but it doesn't have setTimeout() i found workarounds for that then I tried The new javascript Nashorn better performance faster loading, still memory leaking and CPU  also 100%. I realized javascript engines only for little scripts.

Comment: Right; there's no ```setTimeout()``` because that's a browser thing, not a JS thing. How does your workaround work? It also doesn't help that you do ```LINECONTROL[a] = function () ...``` 100+ times rather than reusing a single instance of the function. You can declare it up above, then do ```LINECONTROL[a] = function0;```. That should safe a bunch of memory.

Comment: In javascript it was coded like this for speed I didn't make it but yeah this is the gameboy emulator that's also used by Google Javascript benchmark tests. Even all the opcode instructions are a bunch of functions()'s which nest with other functions() I had to convert it to a switch() in Java, I guess making a bunch of functions is faster javascript then using conditionals. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zixan/GameBoy-Online/master/js/GameBoyCore.js

Comment: This is an emulator, and people close to the metal tend to like jump tables rather than hoping the compiler/VM optimizes correctly. That, and I think some JS VMs cache functions, but I'm not sure. Any reason you're not just using a Java Gameboy emulator?

Comment: Yeah this guy who made this GameBoy emulator in javascript avoided using if statements/switches as much as possible in critical places,like instead of always checking if(lcdIsOn) nonstop when a command gets executed he already knows it's on and it turns it off by changing LCDCONTROL to to DISPLAYOFFCONTROL when he wants too, so no need for any checking which is a plus I guess if you want this mess.

Comment: Yes I use this Gameboy emulator on my website, but I must run it as a service on my vps server to keep like a saved game when people refresh  my website it always has the game that's on the server-side and to prevent people from editing gb memory to cheat etc. My vps doesn't have any browsers (plus I have to run like 10 of these gb emulators). so i stripped away all the canvas/audio code and i just use it to process the game by inputs people put it from the website. It still processes audio/graphics just the stuff that it needs to write to memory etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clever enum approach. You can use it by doing `ACTIONS[x].act(this)`. It's essentially a type-safe jump table.

Edit: added `getAction`. To use it, do `getAction(a).act(this)`, but at this point, you're better off losing the enum and dispatching directly from a renamed `getAction()`. The only benefits you get from the enum are having only a single instance per enum (only a benefit over non-static inner classes) and the jump table.

```
class Foo {

    protected enum Action {
        FUNCTION_0 {
            public void act(Foo foo) { ... }
        },

        FUNCTION_1 {
            public void act(Foo foo) { ... }
        },

        FUNCTION_2 {
            public void act(Foo foo) { ... }
        },

        FUNCTION_3 {
            public void act(Foo foo) { ... }
        },

        ;

        public abstract void act(Foo foo);
    }

    protected static final Action[] ACTIONS = new Action[154];
    static {
        Arrays.fill(ACTIONS, 0, 143, Action.FUNCTION_0);
        Arrays.fill(ACTIONS, 143, 144, Action.FUNCTION_1);
        Arrays.fill(ACTIONS, 144, 153, Action.FUNCTION_2);
        Arrays.fill(ACTIONS, 153, 154, Action.FUNCTION_3);
    }

        protected Action getAction(int a) {
            if (a < 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentError(); }
            else if (a < 143) { return Action.FUNCTION_0; }
            else if (a < 144) { return Action.FUNCTION_1; }
            else if (a < 153) { return Action.FUNCTION_2; }
            else if (a < 154) { return Action.FUNCTION_3; }
            else { throw new IllegalArgumentError(); }
        }
}
```

Comment: Not to bad. But I want to keep it basic without arrays. I want to ask you this question too where it says `(a == 143)` why does it call inside it `LINECONTROL[144]();` if `144` isn't created yet?

Comment: *why does it call inside it LINECONTROL[144](); if 144 isn't created yet?*

That's *in* the function code, and the function hasn't been called, yet. By the time the function's called (rather than constructed), the other values will have been initialized.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to declare and run, do ```(function() { ... })()```, but I usually only do this as a scoping trick to not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Oh so there isn't any recursion then thats what I was worried about, I guess it wouldn't be hard to remove the while and replace it with a few if statements. and renamed initalizeLCD to the `getLINECONTROL(int scanline)`